# Subscribing to AWS AppSync with C++

Tags: c++, mqtt, aws-appsync

I'm trying to create a mqtt connection using a presigned url return from a subscription query to AWS appsync.

The presigned url looks like this:
`wss://iotendpoint-ats.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mqtt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AAAAAAAAAAAA%2F20200203%2Fus-west-2%2Fiotdevicegateway%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200203T190240Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=<signature>&X-Amz-Security-Token=<token>`

Currently I'm trying to use the MQTTClient in the [aws-crt-cpp](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-crt-cpp/blob/master/include/aws/crt/mqtt/MqttClient.h) library as follows:

```
char * url = "wss://iotendpoint-ats.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mqtt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AAAAAAAAAAAA%2F20200203%2Fus-west-2%2Fiotdevicegateway%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200203T190240Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=<signature>&X-Amz-Security-Token=<token>"

Aws::Crt::Mqtt::MqttClient *mqttClient = new Aws::Crt::Mqtt::MqttClient(bootstrap);

std::shared_ptr<Aws::Crt::Mqtt::MqttConnection> mqttConnection = mqttClient->NewConnection(url, 443, Aws::Crt::Io::SocketOptions(), true);
```

However I get the following error:
`aws-c-io: AWS_IO_DNS_INVALID_NAME, Host name was invalid for dns resolution.`

I can open a websocket connection using curl, so I know the url is valid.  It seems that the library cannot handle parameters in the websocket endpoint.  Has anyone had any luck creating a MQTT subscription using a presigned url in c++?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set a WebsocketInterceptor on the mqttConnection.  For details see: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-crt-cpp/issues/97